# MissingServletRequestPartException request part is not present

Tags: spring

My Rest Web Service recieve a Json Object and  Multipartfile,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "saveWithDoc", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> saveWithDoc(@RequestPart Document document,
        @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile doc) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ...
    return DocumentService.saveWithDoc(document, doc);
}
```

The I am using Rest Advanced Client to try it, but I dont have sucess.
I am supposed I am sending the object document required by web service and file in the tab Files I choose one.

[image]

In my server I have this exception:

> { "timestamp": 1503683667950, "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request",
>   "exception":
>   "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
>   "message": "Required request part 'document' is not present", "path":
>   "/myproject-ws/api/Document/saveWithDoc" }

In my request I have this:

> POST /myproject-ws/api/Document/saveWithDoc HTTP/1.1 HOST:
>   localhost:8490 content-length: 511 content-type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary2ppEQ78lS5rcLD9g cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=x-MM0NMFbWD849tDvD07hzXykWyq4TrBuvq2BLEK.andres-hp-250-g4-notebook-pc;
>   XSRF-TOKEN=a27b10b4-1ee1-4434-b3a5-4f6037a19561 x-xsrf-token:
>   a27b10b4-1ee1-4434-b3a5-4f6037a19561
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary2ppEQ78lS5rcLD9g Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc"; filename="claves" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> Text in document
>
> fb34cee6-2366-4335-9952-26a31d4ddc28
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundary2ppEQ78lS5rcLD9g Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"
>
> {"Config":{"id":1 }}
>   ------WebKitFormBoundary2ppEQ78lS5rcLD9g--

What would be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Edited Rest Api:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "saveWithDoc", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> saveWithDoc(@RequestPart(value="document") Document document,
        @RequestPart(value="doc", required = false) MultipartFile doc) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ....
    return personDocumentService.saveWithDoc(personDocument, doc);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your updated controller code as well?

Comment: Rest Controller is the same buddy and I would like to comment that I have tested with Postman without success! I get the same error.

Comment: You need to change the signature of your controller to @RequestPart("document") Document document, @RequestPart(value = "doc", required = false) MultipartFile doc

Comment: Incredibly....I have edited the controller but I have the same problem in Postman and Rest Advanced Client.

Comment: Is commons-fileupload dependency or jar present in your codebase? and Content-Type: application/json should be available in document part like this -  `------WebKitFormBoundary2ppEQ78lS5rcLD9g Content-Type: application/json Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"

{"Config":{"id":1 }} ------WebKitFormBoundary2ppEQ78lS5rcLD9g--`

Comment: The problem is Postman or ARC because I have uploaded docs with an AngularJS client. But I would like to try news method with this clients, so you can be sure the codebase  is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set contentType with boundary like

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=e6e95273-cafb-4dbf-86b8-a1c0ed85b5c5
```

For one of my app, the JSON will look like -

```
`--e6e95273-cafb-4dbf-86b8-a1c0ed85b5c5
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bulkAction"; filename="blob"

 {
     "operation": "notification"        
 }`

--e6e95273-cafb-4dbf-86b8-a1c0ed85b5c5
Content-Type: text/csv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile1.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<Base64OfDocument>
--e6e95273-cafb-4dbf-86b8-a1c0ed85b5c5--
```

My RestController code will look like for endpoint POST /proserv/account/{accountId}/envelopes/bulk

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/{accountId}/envelopes/bulk", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        "multipart/form-data" })
@ResponseBody
public EnvelopeUpdateStatus bulkUpdateService(@RequestPart("bulkAction") BulkAction bulkAction, @PathVariable String accountId,
        HttpServletRequest request, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile... files) {

}
```

In my code MultipartFile... means code can take more than one document. I have tested this REST call using POSTMAN client.

@RequestPart("bulkAction") in the method comes from the JSON part (name should match) and @RequestPart("file") is the actual document (in my case it is a csv), (name should match)

Comment: Please can you check edited question,Thanks, I am using Rest Advanced Client right now, but  I have tried with Postman before.