# Mapping angular Scope object to Java RestController

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-restcontroller

I am having a scope Object in Angular Controller.

When I try to pass it onto Spring Rest Controller , the control is passed to Spring rest controller. But when I try to print the value its getting printed as `null`.

Scenario:

AngularController :

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
    url : '/uploadTemplate',
    data : {
        multipartFile : file,
        am : appMaster
    }
});
```

RestController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadTemplate", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public StringResponse uploadFiles(MultipartFile multipartFile,ApplicationMaster am) {
        System.out.println("Inside");

        System.out.println(am.getAbbreviation());
        System.out.println(am.getAppId());
        System.out.println(am.getName());
}
```

The first `System.out.println` **Inside** is getting printed in console , but next the values of **am** object are printed as `null`.

If I alert the values in `AngularController` , the desired values are alerted.

Comment: First of all you should send a multipart request to the server not a regular request. second you need a `@RequestBody` on the `ApplicationMaster` object to unmarshall the request body.

Comment: I tried with it, but still the same issue.
If i give RequestBody on the ApplicationMaster object, the control doesnt come to restcontroller.
i.e , None of the System.out.println statements are executed.

Comment: Well no it won't because, as stated, you should be sending a multipart request. You are sending JSON with 2 attributes which will be marshaled onto the `ApplicationMaster`. I strongly suggest a read of the spring reference guide and how (un)marshaling JSON works.

Comment: Is there any other alternative?
Any pointers on ** how to send multipart request **  will also be helpfull.

Thanks : )

Comment: @M.Deinum ,
Any other alternative?
Is there any way to convert scope object , so as to get values mapped to rest controller?
Help me out!!

Thanks

Comment: @M. Stefanczuk 
Can you help me on this?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889356/3530898, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810352/how-to-upload-a-multipart-file-using-angular-js-spring-mvc and http://www.uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs/